# Capturing Div contents to image using HTML2Canvas not returing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html2canvas

I am using this code to capture an image displayed within a Div using html2canvas:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= btnCapture.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                html2canvas($('#chart_div'), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        var img = canvas.toDataURL();
                        window.open(img);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

The code works and opens a new browser window with URL something in base64, but the image is not visible.

Why the image is not visible?

Comment: Seems like it is some problem with the data in `div#chart_div`. Show us some more code, or prepare a working demo (e.g. using [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)).

Comment: I am using Google Charts which are rendered in a Div with ID 'chart_div'. There is nothing more HTML code.

Comment: Google Charts renders something in your `div` and it might help us identify the problem. In the mean time add `background: "red", onrendered:...` and try again. (I suspect the image might be indeed rendering, but nothing in it.)

Comment: Please see the Google Chart code here with the same Div there: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart

Comment: This seems to be working fine for me. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/n97Rm/. I really need to see some of **your** code to spot the problem.

Comment: From your Fiddle I realized that I have not added CSS and the canvas tag in code.

Comment: I can't imagine how this would be a problem. Here: I removed both CSS and the canvas and it is still working (http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/n97Rm/). Neither of them is actually needed for the html2canvas to work.

Comment: @ExpertSystem I tried your fiddle and it works but for some reason i need to refresh the page to see the image (or press F12 for the developer tools, it seems that on resize it shows up)

Comment: @RickyStam: That's strange. I see the image right away ! What browser/version are you using ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m

Comment: @RickyStam: Yeah, me too. Still I get to see the image right away. I don't knw what to say. Do you get any errors in the console ?

Comment: Nop no errors in the console

Answer (score 1):

using:"html2canvasproxy.ashx"

```
            html2canvas($('#chart_div'), {
            "logging": true,
            "proxy": "html2canvasproxy.ashx",                    
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
```